# Slack API admin.roles.listAssignments return feature_not_enabled

Tags: api, slack, slack-api

I am trying to run the Slack API [admin.roles.listAssignments](https://api.slack.com/methods/admin.roles.listAssignments) but I have this error
`{ "ok": false, "error": "feature_not_enabled" }`

Is there a way to enabled this feature ? What does the error message mean ?

Comment: That endpoint has some restrictions. You would need to be an admin user on an Enterprise Grid plan for it to work. Unfortunately, there is no equivalent endpoint in the open api.

Comment: Hi @sandra for your quick reply,
Do you know if there is a developer license for enterprise ?
I want to create an app for Slack directory but my company doesn't work with slack and doesn't need an Entreprise Grid plan

Comment: I believe there is a way, but you'll need to reach out to the Slack Platform support team to get the ball rolling. feedback@slack.com 